# Cómo usar sequelize para guardar registros en relaciones uno a muchos?

Tags: sequelize.js

Cómo usar sequelize para guardar registros en relaciones uno a muchos?.

Para recuperar registros con modelos relacionados en sequelize puedo usar  eager loading (carga ansiosa ). Cómo puedo grabar, al tiempo, registros con instrucciones de sequelize en asociaciones uno a muchos?. Gracias.

Relación uno a muchos. onetomany. Tengo una factura. la factura tiene un encabezado y un detalle. En el encabezado, tipos de datos que no se repiten como el número de la factura, nombre del negocio, su identificación tributaria, dirección, nombre del cliente, fecha. Y en el detalle están los diferentes productos vendidos con la cantidad, impuestos, el precio y el nombre. Tengo, entonces una factura y muchos productos. inicialmente no puse ejemplos porque considero que se presta para confusión pues los nombres de las cosas, objetos o documentos suelen ser diferentes en cada país pero, el ejemplo expuesto, enmarca mi necesidad. Gracias.

Comment: No esta muy clara tu pregunta, podrias dar mas detalle? o poner algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Envio con axios un objeto que contiene las propiedades de la factura y un arreglo del detalle. Este arreglo proviene del carrito de compras. En el servidor leo los datos provenientes y separo la data como encabezado y detalle. El encabezado lo guardo en la tabla ventas y el detalle lo guardo con modelo.bulkCreate(). Entrego el código empleado:

archivo ventas.js

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

```
**const venta = model.Venta.build**({
    factura: req.body.factura,
    archPdf: req.body.archPdf,
    cliente: req.body.cliente,
    cedula: req.body.cedula,
    fechaExpedicion: req.body.fechaExpedicion,
    fechaDeEntrega: req.body.fechaDeEntrega,
    fechaDeVencimiento: req.body.fechaDeVencimiento,
    numArticulos: req.body.numArticulos,
    total: req.body.total,
    totalIva: req.body.totalIva,
    impuestoAlConsumo: req.body.impuestoAlConsumo,
    elaboradoPor: req.body.elaboradoPor,
    fechaDeElaboracion: req.body.fechaDeElaboracion,
    descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
    saldo: req.body.saldo
})
//
const detalleFac = req.body.detalle

//
**venta.save()** // Persistente
.then(function(response) {
    return response
})
.then(function(respuesta){
    console.log(detalleFac);
    //////////////////
    **return model.DetalleVenta.bulkCreate(
            detalleFac**
        )
    .then(function (detalleventas) {
        console.log("DETALLE PRODUCTO VENDIDO");
        console.log(detalleventas)
        console.log("Creados DETALLE VENTAS de varios productos");

    })
    /////////////
    res.end(JSON.stringify(respuesta))
})
.catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(error) {
    console.log("Errores de validación:", error);
    for (var i in error.errors) {
        console.log('Error en el campo:', error.errors[i].value);
    };

    res.send({"validez": false})

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
    res.send({"validez": false})
});
//
```

});